# I am bit confused with the following sentence

Tags: grammaticality

What the different between "So exciting to be part of it" and "So excited to be part of it"

which one is correct?

Comment: Not much difference.

Comment: They're both correct, but they mean different things. Both are the result of [Conversational Deletion](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/66994/15299), but from different sentences: _**It is** so exciting .._ versus _**I am** so excited .._ The boldface part is what's deleted.

Comment: @HotLicks Quite a bit, in fact. See also, Prof Lawler's comment.

Comment: Welcome to ELU. Please visit [ell.se]. Good Luck.

Comment: I’m with HotLicks - there is little to separate them in terms of meaning. When someone pronounces a personal opinion about what is and isn’t exciting (“It is so exciting...”) they are effectively saying “**It is** so exciting... **for me**.” This puts it very close to the same meaning as, “**I’m** so excited...”.